# Non-recursive formula for a ring-like structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, recurrence-relations

I am working with a ring alike structure (A,+,.) where (A,+,0) is an abelian group, (A,.,1) a monoid but... product does not distribute (left or right) over sum operation. As I construct rank-3 tensors using (A,.,1) vectors, all Power Set computations (t^k, t:random tensor, k integer) searching for multiplicative period distribution (Monte-Carlo) over that space, I work recursively step-by-step using the respective + and . substructures.

I wonder if this recursively calculations are forced by the non-distributivity condition and if this were not the case, if any non-recursive formula for powers could be derived.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. It seems to me that all expressions involving multiple applications of binary operations are recursive. Using associativity or distributivity simply make those expression 'easier' to write (since they allow you to reorganize.) So I guess that is my first reaction to the implied question in your last sentence. The entire sentence beginning with "As I construct rank-3 tensors..." completely baffles me :)

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, it was confusing. I rephrase:A is a group, but including additive unit 0 transforms multiplication table into a monoid. The elements of A are integer vectors like (1 3 8 4 2), so a n-square matrix of them are rank-3 tensors. As no distribution (. over +) holds, the tensors behave like a magma (with unity=unit matrix). All powers of tensors are calculated recursively, my question is to calculate powers non-recursivelly

Comment: Until now, exploration shows that rank-3 tensors dot product form a non-associative magma with unit.

Comment: Here are some answers:Smarandache Near-rings 
 
W. B. Vasantha Kandasamy